# How to collaborate on a forked project?

Tags: git, github

When making a fork I find that the issues tab is gone. Where do we write about our progress in the fork?

What is the standard way of working on a fork? I will be involved in a long running project that will be working on a fork of a project, and we would like our own wiki and issues tab where we can discuss what we are doing in the fork. Is this not how things work at github since I can't find these things in my fork?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179468/forking-a-repo-on-github-but-allowing-new-issues-on-the-fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to "Settings".

   [image]
2. Under "Features", check the box next to "wikis" and next to "issues". Just like when you create a repo. These things aren't on by default.

   [image]